# Laravel return to view before edit when edit is called from multiple places

Tags: laravel

I have an edit form that gets called from 2 different views. How do I return to the correct view after I edit the form? Do I have to pass the calling view to the edit page then to the controller to return back to or is there a better way?

**attendee/index.blade**

```
 <td>{{link_to_route('attendee.edit','',$attendee->id, array(
    'class'=>'edit-attendee btn btn-info btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-pencil',
    'data-title' => 'Edit Attendee'))}} </td>
```

**register/index.blade**

```
 <td>{{link_to_route('attendee.edit','',$attendee->id, array(
    'class'=>'edit-attendee btn btn-info btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-pencil',
    'data-title' => 'Edit Attendee'))}} </td>
```

**edit.blade**

```
{{ Form::model($attendee, array('class'=>'form-horizontal', 'method' => 'PATCH', 'route' => array('attendee.update', $attendee->id))) }}
     ...irrelevant stuff...
        <div class=pull-right>
        {{Form::submit('Update',array('class'=>'btn btn-success'))}}
        <a href = "{{URL::previous()}}" class = 'btn btn-warning'>Cancel</a>
        </div>
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**controller**

```
public function update($id)
{
    $attendee = Attendee::findOrFail($id);

    $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), Attendee::$rules);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput()->with('id', $id);
    }

    $attendee->update($data);

    return Redirect::route('attendees.index');
}
```

Comment: `Redirect::back` / `Redirect::refresh`?

Comment: i think that just goes back to the edit page where the form is.

Comment: Redirect::intended()

Comment: that takes me back to my main index page :(

Answer (score 0):

Jeffrey Way always says, "When in doubt, create a new controller."  Might be worthwhile advice in this case.  `AttendeesController.php` can handle the "regular" edits, and a new `RegisterAttendeesController.php` for those coming from the registration page?  For consistency between controllers, use a static method in the model for doing the updates, and return separate views.